# How do I track files viewable under "show clean" in Sourcetree?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to merge two Construct 2 (xml-based game engine) projects by making two separate commits, each belonging to a separate branch, and then merging the two.

After the initial commit into the A branch, I replace the files in the folder with project B, but these new files don't show up in the Unstaged files list.

Well, they show up under `"show only - clean"` and `"show only - all"`, but I can't stage them.

How do I fix this and what does a clean file mean?

Answer (score 0):

In branchA you added the projectA and committed. Then you should create a new branch by **branch -> new branch Tab -> create branch**.

Now you can add projectB in working directly. You should select `show only – all` to see the projectB in unstaged file list.

Finally you can merge the two branches.